# Unexpected T_STRING. how to reroute a new subdirectory with php

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, subdirectory, parse-error

This is probably a simple fix. Basically, when trying to reroute a wordpress subdirectory the file contents I've moved is unable to 'open stream' for the directory, showing;

```
Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required './shop/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/jackpier/public_html/onemilehigh.co.uk/shop/index.php on line 17
```

So, I've been trying to include the `(include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')` into my index.php, but am then showed-

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/jackpier/public_html/onemilehigh.co.uk/shop/index.php on line 17
```

I must be integrating it incorrectly but don't know in what way.
I am really inexperienced with php

Here's my current code:

```
    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require('./shop/wp-blog-header.php'); path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php');
```

Again, probably really simple.

Comment: Invalid assignment syntax, not a variable, and that approach wouldn't work anyway. Where did you find that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [include_path='.;C:\php5\pear'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547333/include-path-c-php5-pear)

Comment: Probably the manual page of [`require`](http://php.net/require) is of help?

Comment: thanks ill have a look, can always go for the long winded install which i think i'll have to go for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
require('./shop/wp-blog-header.php'); path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php');  
                                      ^^^^ a 'constant'
```

What you're attempting to do doesn't work in PHP. If you're trying to change the include path, that's done via `ini_set('include_path', ...)`, and must be done BEFORE you try to include/require a file. You do not do this by dumping some random junk onto the same line as an require directive.

Answer (score 1):

```
path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php');
```

should be

```
path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php';
```

You had an extra `)`

**Edit**

And also read what Marc said in his answer and his comment on this one.

Comment: Doesn't work anyways. you can't assign values to a constant (since it's `path`, not `$path`) this way anyways. Either way it's a syntax error.

Comment: Good call! Just guessed there would only be one obvious issue.